# typo in tooltip for Needs Improvement button

Tags: bug, status-completed

If you hover over the `Needs Improvement` button on the [Community Evaluation](https://askubuntu.com/review/community-eval) page, a tooltip will pop up that says `this question and its ansewrs need improvement`:

[image: this tooltip needs improvement]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is network-wide or just affects Ask Ubuntu, so I'm posting it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This very critical bug will be fixed in the next build.  Thank you for your cooperation citizen!

Seriously though, we appreciate every bug report, big or small - keep them coming.

Comment: heehee…you're welcome! X3